# Using customPages in DynamicData

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

Im doing an asp.net project with dynamic data.

I've used a hyperlink to navigate to a new page which I have created, which isnt iside te dynamic data folder. This works fine, but to keep everything tidy i've tried to do the same by adding an aspx page inside the custom pages, so where inside Bill folder I have details, edit,insert,list I now have 'UpdateBillPrices'

Although when I navigate to this I am getting the 'page cant be found error'
is this because its running inside the dynamic data folders?

the path is not wrong btw ta

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a custom List Page for a DB table and POCO named Foo, then you would add a Page named List.aspx to the folder DynamicData/CustomPages/Foo/ .